# VeraCrypt: Is it possible to change the password after an encrypted container has been created?

Tags: passwords, password-management, veracrypt

I would like to know whether it is possible to change the password after an encrypted container has been created? The password I chose was a bit weak, and I would like to be able to modify it without having to extract all the data, delete the container, recreate it with the new password, and then shift the data back to the container (plus, in this way some evidence of the files would remain on the hard disk due to the way NTFS undelete can be exploited).

So, can I change the password after creating the container?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't change the random key with what everything is encrypted but just the encryption of this key. So yes, it is perfectly possible and therefore you have a menu entry under "System" for doing exactly this.

How this works in detail is basically answered [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/18479/how-does-truecrypt-change-password-without-the-need-for-a-complete-re-encryption).

**Implement in VeraCrypt desktop version 1.24-Update4**: *Menu bar* > *Volumes* > *Change Volume Password…*

Comment: Thanks. Basically just `System | Change Password...`.

Comment: Is a potentially very time consuming re-encryption required when changing it?